# Image not uploading in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have uploaded an image in admin portal
but it is not rendering in html template
how can i solve this?
below are the source codes!
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from PIL import Image

class Question(models.Model):
    question_relation=models.ForeignKey('Answer',related_name='ques',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='levels/media/')
    text=models.TextField(blank=True,max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question_relation)
```

html file

```
 <div style="margin-left:35%;margin-right:35%">
       <img src="{{Question.question_image.url}}" alt="">
            <form class="post-form" method="post">
            {%csrf_token%}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <script>var editor=new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>

        </div>
```

i have included these in my urls.py

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

on checking the inspect element in img src it appears as (unknown).
i dont know why it is not able to pick up the url of image

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL="/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'levels/media')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import *
from . import models
from django import forms
from .forms import CheckAnswer
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Question

# Create your views here.
@login_required
def Arena1(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CheckAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('thanks')
    else:
        form=CheckAnswer()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'levels/arena1.html',args)
```

Comment: Post your html form.

Comment: posted please check and help--@PankajSharma

Comment: i tried it. but still not displaying image.when i just checked inspect element the img tag didnot have any src in it it states unknown there...please help--@PankajSharma

Comment: not displaying ? is it uploading or not ?

Comment: check in your admin panel, whether the image is uploaded successfully or not?

Comment: also post your views

Comment: yes in admin portal it is displaying. In admin whin i click the image link it displays the image -@PankajSharma

Comment: post your views

Comment: postedplease help asap! -@PankajSharma

Comment: you are not rending any `Question` object from views then how can you use `Question` in your html

Comment: so using data=Question.objects.all()would solve this?? -@PankajSharma

Comment: You check if the form is valid and then redirect without doing anything with your form's data... If that's a ModelForm, you're supposed to call `form.save()` #facepalm#

Comment: no Question must be an object of `Question`,  like you can use  - `args['Question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=1)`

Comment: not beneficial. problem persists still-@PankajSharma

Comment: can you please provide me the modifications which i need to do in pioece of code...updates code of mine.. It would be really helpful--@PankajSharma

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Update your form as -

```
<form class="post-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

When you are writing client-side code, all you need to know is use multipart/form-data when your form includes any  elements.If you want know why see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).